# JQuery fileDownload get error on fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

This is what I have:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.fileDownload/1.4.2/jquery.fileDownload.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience", function () {
        $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'))
          .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
          .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });

        return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download
      });
    });
  </script>
```

that must work with

```
<a href="" class="fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience" href="http://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin">AAAA</a>
```

For some reason the download fails and I get the related error: `File download error!`. I hope I solved the part with that cookie `fileDownload` with value `True` in my python code, but not sure.

How can I see why the download fails?
I think it must be related to this: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js#L226

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of double `href` attribute. `<a href="" class="fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience" href="http://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin">AAAA</a>`

The first `href` has priority.